# How to find vowels in a string in java program

Tags: java, function

What is the java coding to find out vowels in a string?
How to use OR operator in java? 
because the symbol " || " is not taken while i executing the java program.

Comment: Have a look at indexOf function of String

Comment: Seems to be several questions here. Please elaborate and include relevant code.

Comment: Please put the code which you are using

Comment: you can follow the answer 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51471847/how-do-you-use-charat-with-an-array/51472539#51472539

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the below code 
The program  iterats over the given string and check if each character is an vowel
1. The symbol '||' can be used as OR, below program is an example

```
  public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        String str ="This is a test";
        for(int i=0;i <str.length();i++){
            if((str.charAt(i) == 'a') || 
                (str.charAt(i) == 'e')  ||
                (str.charAt(i) == 'i') || 
                (str.charAt(i) == 'o') ||
                (str.charAt(i) == 'u')) {
                System.out.println(" The String contains " + str.charAt(i));
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Note: it will match only lower case vowels

Comment: You could have used RegEx and saved a lot of typing and improved your code readability.

Comment: yes , correct. I thought of explaining with string functions will be easier to understand

Answer (score 3):

**String** class has the **contains** method which can be used to find out whether a **String** value have vowels or not. It also has **matches** method which can be used to match characters using regular expressions.